# What are the recomended ways to manage a django project in production (in apache server)

Tags: python, django, apache, daemon

My goal is to have the django app automatically restart whenever it crashes, and to write the error to a log file. There are suggestions to use supervisord, daemontools, or django-supervisor, but i'm having issues getting any of them to work.

For example, in supervisord, the application is prompting me for a "program" to manage, and it want's a directory. I have no clue what this actually means. What is the "program" that overlaps all of my django project if I want to manage it?

I set it to this:

```
[progam:webserver]
command=/home/user/apps/django/apache2/bin/start # I think this is wrong
restart=true
logfile=/home/path/to/file
```

But I don't think this is correct. I don't know the fundamentals behind webservers and how it interacts with something like a django app or mod_wsgi.

I guess tl;dr there are three questions. One is how do you guys recommend managing a django project in apache. And second, how should I configure my supervisord to hook onto my django project? [EDIT] And a third question, besides logging crashes, what other cool features should be added to managing a web app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you're running django with apache, supervisor shouldn't be necessary.  When django errors it will happen inside of an apache request.  Apache is already a service.  It might be important to keep track of how many requests apache is handling or its resource usage, but there are nice open source tools for this (one of which is nagios).

Some python webservers ( i believe gunicorn) can (maybe should?) be managed using supervisor.  With apache, though, this shouldn't be necessary.

Apache will handle logging to the error log you set up in the virtualhost.  In addition you can have django email you on errors (i think is pretty cool)
django-sentry looks really cool https://github.com/getsentry/sentry.  It provides a nice management of errors.

Comment: But does it restart the django app? I think this is a critical feature along with logging.

Comment: yes when a request comes i believe a new django app is started for every request so django isn't actually running.

Comment: Oh wow, so I guess supervisord isn't even needed then. Why is supervisor even a service then? For people who don't use apache as their server?

Comment: supervisor is extremely useful just not in this instance.  like you can turn any script into a service `while True: #do something` can be turned into a service and restarted when error

Comment: Ah thanks, so just for future reference, how could django be hooked up to supervisord? What is actually the central process that keeps django running? command=/home/apps/django/apache/start probably isn't it lol.

Comment: django is never running by itself.  It runs inside of a webserver. Using `python manage runserver.py` might give the illusion that django is runnign but even runserver is just a lightweight webserver

Comment: Oh, so actually command=/home/apps/django/apache/start actually looks sort correct, but i'm still not sure lol. What is the key apache process that keeps everything running? I kinda just assumed it was start because that made the most sense.

Comment: i have only used ubuntu but apache is managed by init.d or upstart, which provide an interface to manage services in linux